# Различия между Action Script и Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

Поясните разницу между этими двумя языками, какой где применяется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ИМХО: Flash - это не язык, ближайшее слово для описания - платформа, набор средств для создания медиа контента, игр, приложений, и их доставки потребителю.

А ActionScript (3), да язык, для создания приложений/программ исполняемых на Flash платформе. От баннеров до игр и тяжелых насыщенных корпоративных приложений (Flex).

Как платформа (Flash а следовательно и ас3) может применяться/запускаться практически везде, веб/соц приложения, desktop (win/mac), мобильные (android/ios).

Думаю что в связи с приходом приставок последнего поколения на х86/х64 архитектуру (слава богу), следует скоро ждать появления средств разработки Flash контента и для этих систем. (вернее средства и среды есть, нужен проигрыватель / вирт машина)

Answer (score 1):

Flash - это не язык, это технология, которая позволяет на веб страница в интернете размещать различный контент(от игр, до видео).

AS3 - это язык с помощью, которого можно создавать такой контент.

.swf - это формат(особая структура) файла, который и есть тот самый контент, который подкладывается.

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript — объектно-ориентированный язык программирования, один из диалектов ECMAScript, который добавляет интерактивность, обработку данных и многое другое в содержимое Flash-приложений. ActionScript исполняется виртуальной машиной (ActionScript Virtual Machine), которая является составной частью Flash Player. ActionScript компилируется в байт-код, который включается в SWF-файл.

Ссылка на [wiki >>>](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript)

Ide поддерживающие action script 3.0: Flash Builder, Flash Develop, Eclipse, Astella и др.